# Serializing an object and storing it to a varbinary field in a DB

Tags: database, serialization, varbinary

I can serialize an object to a file using:

```
var writeStream = File.Open("l.osl", FileMode.Create);
var bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
bformatter.Serialize(writeStream, l);
```

What I am trying to do is instead of writing it to a file, write it to a DB varbinary field.
I assume that I have to change writeStream to something else, but what? Can I just put an object in there and there insert that object into the DB (I'm using LINQ).

Will this work?

PS: I have looked around and can't find any solid examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing C# data structure into a SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217187/storing-c-sharp-data-structure-into-a-sql-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of close to this:

[Storing C# data structure into a SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217187/storing-c-data-structure-into-a-sql-database)